# GCD - Enqueuing of thread -

Tags: multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

Can someone help me to understand thread enqueuing while using GCD.
I want to understand thread enqueuing which we see while putting breakpoints.
How does it work?

Do every thread executes on either main or global queue? Is it the reason  of enqueuing?

Thanks,

Comment: Hey, anyone has idea about it? Please clarify.

Comment: srus2017, FWIW, I’d encourage you to search the Apple WWDC videos for introductions to Grand Central Dispatch. There are lots of wonderful videos that will introduce you to these concepts. https://developer.apple.com/search/?q=gcd&type=Videos

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone help me to understand thread enqueuing while using GCD. I want to understand thread enqueuing which we see while putting breakpoints.

I’d suggest you think of it the other way around. You don’t “enqueue” threads. You dispatch blocks of code to a queue (i.e. “enqueue”), and the dispatch queue will select the appropriate thread on which that code shall run.

[image]

For example, above, I create a queue, dispatched a block of code to that queue, and added a breakpoint. I can see that my queue spun up a thread (it’s “Thread 3” in this case) and I can see that this was “enqueued” from the the `viewDidLoad` method running on the “main thread”.

> Do every thread executes on either main or global queue?

Again, it’s the other way around. Code that is dispatched to a particular queue will trigger that queue to run that block of code on a particular thread.

But there are three types of queues:

- the “main” queue (which runs its code on a single, special, dedicated “main” thread);
- one of the various, shared “global” queues (which will select a background thread from a pool of worker threads and run the code on that thread); or
- a “custom” queue that you create to a custom queue, like above.

> Is it the reason of enqueuing?

This “enqueuing” is merely the process of adding a block of code to a queue. Xcode will try to show you where the code was enqueued, to help you diagnose from where the code was dispatched.